# Get total count and percent from some results

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say have this table:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9xw9aPa42MfuqnxDb3bWvN/2

How can write SQL request for getting:
total count of rows for some user and its percent (rows with some status to total count).

For example:

for user_id = 1 and status = true:

total count = 3
prc = 33% (2 is count with status true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  ROUND(100 * AVG(CASE WHEN state THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 1)  prc, 
  COUNT(*) counter
FROM test_query 
WHERE partnerSteamid64='uuid_1'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9xw9aPa42MfuqnxDb3bWvN/9).
Results:

```
| prc  | counter |
| ---- | ------- |
| 25.0 | 4       |
```

Comment: "counter" should contains all row for the user (for all status) but prc for count with some status to ALL count for current user.

Comment: Then counter should be 4

Comment: So what is your expected result?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9xw9aPa42MfuqnxDb3bWvN/6 in this case (total is 4, prc for status=true is 25% becouse only one row from 4 rows has status = true

Answer (score 0):

Using simple sql syntax

```
select count(*), count(*)*100.0/(select count(*) from test_query) from test_query where partnerSteamid64 = 'uuid_1' and state = true
```

Modify the where condition based on your needs in the main query and in sub-query

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*),
       avg( status::int ) as ratio
FROM some_table
GROUP BY user_id
```

To count `false` values:

```
   avg( (not status)::int ) as ratio
```